# SASS sum of dimensions

Tags: css, html, sass

I have the following SCSS code:

```
#appMain {
    margin-right: 25em + 1em;
}

#appLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

#appRight {
    float: right;
    width: 25em;
    margin-right: -25em - 1em;
}
```

Now I want to use parameters, so I created 2 variables

```
$rightDimension: "25em";
$marginBetween: "1em";
```

When I change the code this way

```
#appMain {
    margin-right: $rightDimension + $marginBetween;
}
```

Instead of getting `26em`, I now get `25em1em` resulting in invalid css and thus, the property doesn't apply.

What am I doing wrong? How can I do this simple math with SASS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you quoted the values, Sass treats them as strings rather than values and does a concatenation instead of an addition (like Javascript would do it as well).

Simply omit the quotes to make it work.

```
$rightDimension: 25em;
$marginBetween: 1em;
```

[working example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/37161e2b8d0582367b2c)